# How to disable street names in android voice navigation?

Tags: stock-android, navigation

I'm stuck with a quite simple problem, still can't find the solution. 
I'd like to disable street names reading in voice navigation, to keep just simple guidance like "turn right" or "turn left". Can't find an option in settings so maybe configuring text to speach engine somehow would help?